# Create custom gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a small problem.

I created custom gradle plugin(standalone plugin) and include it from mavenlocal in my simple project. It is working, but i do not know how to set System property within my plugin. 
More detail: inside my plugin, in task i want to set system property(System.setproperty(key, value)) and get it property from my main app for example in Main class main method, but main method do not se this property

When i create task in build.gradle in my project i can set main, classpath, dependsOn classes and type of task - JacaExec, in this  case i start my task and its working, task sets property, then launches my main method and in main i can get system property.

How can i do the same, but via standalone plugin?
(Sorry for my English, im bad english speaker\writer)

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the `JavaExec` task is [freely available](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/JavaExec.java), so I would suggest you have a look at that for inspiration. As for how they set a system property specifically, see [line 217-221](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/JavaExec.java#L218):

```
    @Override
    public JavaExec systemProperty(String name, Object value) {
        javaExecHandleBuilder.systemProperty(name, value);
        return this;
    }
```